# Discriminating unions between remote actors in F# Akka.Net

Tags: f#, akka.net, f#-data

I have an actor in local machine and an actor in remote machine. Is it possible to pattern match using Discriminating Union of remote actor with local actor. Here is what I am trying with,

Remote actor:

- match msg with

  | Task1 msg -> printf "done"

  | Task2 msg -> printf "completed"

Local actor:

- remoteActor <! Task1 "yes"

I want to send an message from local actor to remote actor like this. But I am unable to send Task1 type from local actor. Any help is appreciable

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specifically prevents you from sending it like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Akka.NET v1.4 uses Newtonsoft's JSON serializer by default, which doesn't work well with discriminated unions. If you switch to the [new Hyperion serializer](https://getakka.net/articles/networking/serialization.html#how-to-setup-hyperion-as-default-serializer), it should work fine. Add the following to your config:

```json
akka {
  actor {
    serializers {
      hyperion = "Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer, Akka.Serialization.Hyperion"
    }
    serialization-bindings {
      "System.Object" = hyperion
    }
  }
}
```

You can then send and receive discriminated unions with no problems. Hyperion will become the default serializer in Akka.NET v1.5.